# Why are some of the old Win16 API's still supported in newer Windows versions?

Tags: windows, winapi, 64-bit, legacy, 16-bit

I was recently fixing some IAT on MoleBox packed executable and saw that it links with kernel32 functions: '_lopen', '_lwrite' and '_lread'. This [site](http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32lread.htm) states that those API's are provided for compatibility with 16-bit versions of Windows. I undesrtand that 'Win16' applications can't be executed in long mode (yes - I'm running Win8.1 x64) - so what is the purpose those to be still included in 'kernel32.dll'?

By the way those functions aren't even included in the 'msdn' library.

EDIT: It also seems that those function aren't actually 16-bit! They're taking 32-bit parameters on the stack.

Comment: Of course they are not 16 bit. `kernel32.dll` is a 32 or 64 bit module. Also, the fact that a function takes 32 bit parameters doesn't make it 32 bit.

Comment: Go spend some time reading the archives at [Raymond Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com//b/oldnewthing), where he frequently discusses the old compatibility code that lingers on.

Comment: Primary reason, surely, is because there was absolutely no point in *not* including them and force programmers to rewrite their old programs.  Implementing them in 32-bit was trivial.

Comment: Funny enough but it seems that those '16-bit' functions are supported in 64-bit modules also! This seems like an enteirly new universe for me. I should maybe create a new question - when to use Win32 or Win16 API.

Comment: I thought I explained this in my answer. I guess I didn't do a good enough job. What did you not understand?

Comment: Don't worry Bro I understand everything.

Comment: "when to use Win32 or Win16 API" - latter is meant for legacy codebase, you should use Win32 API whenever possible. Just because you *can* use obsolete API does not mean you *should*, unless you have special requirement (need target Win3.1 and older)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not that the functions can be called by 16 bit applications. Clearly they cannot because they live in 32 bit and 64 bit modules. The point is (was) to make it easier for developers to compile old programs without having to re-write them.

Now, in 2015 there's no real need to cater for developers that have 16 bit programs that they wish to re-compile. That is probably not happening any more to any significant level. But if you roll back the clock 20 years then this was a real concern. And hence MS included these compat crutches. And once they had been included, then MS probably decided to leave them there so as not to break binary compatibility. MS does go to great lengths to avoid breaking old programs. Were these functions to be removed, any programs that rely on them would break.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft doesn't remove functions "just because" they're old. They will remove these functions as soon as they would require a reimplementation, but for now it takes less work to keep them.